# Why does terminal cursor flash briefly?

Tags: fedora, xterm, cursor

I am using Fedora 20, and whenever a new line opens in the command line terminal, the cursor, which is a solid black rectangle, flashes on and off about ten times, then remains steady. I think I have read somewhere that I can do something useful during the flashing period, but I have forgotten what it was, or where to find the reference again; or am I just imagining it?

Please can someone confirm or explain this?

In response to @sim's query about the terminal emulator:

```
[Harry@localhost ~]$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

Comment: Are you actually using `xterm`?

Comment: This variable just tells applications what specific kind of terminal it is emulating. The default is often `xterm` (here both xterm and xfce-terminal report `xterm`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find anything about "something useful" you can do during that time (though some random undocumented feature would not surprise me). However, it seems that this behavior is to "save energy" (by not having to wake up the GPU and redraw the screen for each blink).

See the [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397234/why-does-the-cursor-freeze-in-terminals), and the (rejected) [GNOME bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=658099).